Incorrect numbering of tables when using both table and xltabular environments
I'm running MacTeX2024 with all updates applied. The program
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xltabular}

\begin{document}   

\begin{table} 
\caption{AAA} 
\end{table} 

\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{X} 
\caption{ZZZ} \\ 
\end{xltabular} 

\end{document}

generates this output:

The second table's number is incorrect. How can I fix it?
About my TeX distribution:

MacTeX2024

pdfTeX Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (TeX Live 2024)

LaTeX2e <2024-11-01>

L3 programming layer <2024-11-02>

xltabular 2024/10/28 v2.0g



Same thing with an up-to-date 2024 TeX Live distribution, on ubuntu 24.04, with  LuaHBTeX, Version 1.18.0.

Works fine on my Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS machine, LuaHBTeX, Version 1.18.0 (TeX Live 2024)

It hit me too and I have a first fix but need to check if it is hyperref compatible.

see https://github.com/rolfn/xltabular/issues/23

The faulty-numbering issue reported in the above query has led to an udpate of the xltabular package. As of xltabular 2024/11/13 v0.2h, the numbering issue appears to have been solved. Many thanks to the package's maintainers -- Rolf Niepraschk and Herbert Voss -- for their quick work!
Aside: Observe that the package's version number has gone from 2024/10/28 v2.0g to 2024/11/13 v0.2h.
